# Integrating MVC projects

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am having an requirement to add a project into the existing one. Existing one is MVC 4.0 and using Dot net framework 4.5 application and is using DBML (Linq to SQL classes). The one which I want to add is using EDMX  in Dot net Framework 4.0.Edmx is also of lower version. Versioning problem is solved by explicitly defining in Web.Config File. But the thing is both of the projects are building successfully but throwing exception at run time and the exception is :: 
Schema specified is not valid. Errors:

App_Code.Model.csdl(3,4) : error 0019: The EntityContainer name must be unique. An EntityContainer with the name 'calendarEntities' is already defined.

and this is coming for every controller where it is being used.

Please help me As I am not clear with how to get rid off this error.

Comment: You are going down a bad path, do you have a manager just trying to find something for you to do? What is the point of integrating the 4.0 project into a 4.5 project if you aren't upgrading to at least upgrade the 4.0 project to 4.5?

Comment: But Sir, How can I proceed then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because there are specific instances where different versions can be supported, when used incorrectly trying to make mismatched versions of things can lead to what is essentially an unsupported project. This is because mismatched version configurations are not extensively tested and even if you were to call Microsoft support the first thing that they would tell you is to upgrade all of your projects to the same version of the runtime. So that is what I would recommend and if you have a specific issue please post the code and enough of the error so that help can be provided.